# How to verify to call or not to call a method

Tags: unit-testing, dart, mockito, flutter

```
class MockView extends Mock implements ContactListViewContract {

  @override
  void onLoadContactsComplete(List<Contact> items) {

  }
  @override
  void onLoadContactsError() {}

}

void main() {

  test('ContactListPresenter test', () {
    Injector.configure(Flavor.MOCK);
    MockView view = new MockView();

    ContactListPresenter presenter = new ContactListPresenter(view);

    presenter.loadContacts();

    verify(view.onLoadContactsComplete).called(1);

  });

}
```

I want to make sure when `presenter.loadContacts()` is called from the code, then verify `view.onLoadContactsComplete` is called also but getting an error:

> Used on a non-mockito object

Is there a possibility to do this with Mockito?

Update:

```
abstract class ContactListViewContract {
  void onLoadContactsComplete(List<Contact> items);
  void onLoadContactsError();
}
```

here the `onLoadContactsComplete` method is called

```
class ContactListPresenter {
  ContactListViewContract _view;
  ContactRepository _repository;

  ContactListPresenter(this._view){
    _repository = new Injector().contactRepository;
  }

  void loadContacts(){
    assert(_view != null);

    _repository.fetch()
        .then((contacts) {
          print(contacts);
          _view.onLoadContactsComplete(contacts); // here the onLoadContactsComplete method is called
        }).catchError((onError) {
          print(onError);
          _view.onLoadContactsError();
        });
  }

}
```

Mocked Repository. Fetch mocked data.

```
class MockContactRepository implements ContactRepository{

  Future<List<Contact>> fetch(){
    return new Future.value(kContacts);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

when calling `verify` method you need call the actual method on the mock

Try

```
test('ContactListPresenter test', () async {
    Injector.configure(Flavor.MOCK);
    MockView view = new MockView();

    ContactListPresenter presenter = new ContactListPresenter(view);

    presenter.loadContacts();

    await untilCalled(view.onLoadContactsComplete(typed(any))); 
    //completes when view.onLoadContactsComplete(any) is called

    verify(view.onLoadContactsComplete(typed(any))).called(1);

});
```

If the method was not called once, the test will fail.

Comment: may be due to the fact that the method (onLoadContactsComplete) called in the Future?

Comment: I tried `verify(view.onLoadContactsComplete(kContacts)).called(1);` but get the same error: `Used on a non-mockito object `. Method onLoadContactsComplete is 100% called.

Comment: I got the `Used on a non-mockito object`  error because mocked view implements **abstract** `class ContactListViewContract`. I created a new class implements `ContactListViewContract` and already mocked it and  tried your option with async - and it all worked! Thank you!

Comment: Which is the difference between untilCalled and verify? I mean, if `untilCalled(view.onLoadContactsComplete(typed(any)))` is successful, isn't the `verify(view.onLoadContactsComplete(typed(any))).called(1)`
 useless? It's just checking again that that method is called

Answer (score 1):

[Mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) provides native support for both

1. To test that your method has been called at least once you can use
   `verify(<your-method-with-expected-params>)` this will verify that your method has called (no matter how many times). To verify that it has been called for a specific number of times you can chain it with `.called(<number-of-calls-expected>)`
2. To test that your method hasn't been called you should use `verifyNever(<your-method-with-expected-params>)` this will validate that your method hasn't been invoked

Make sure that the method passed to both `verify` and `verifyNever` are the methods which have been Mocked by Mockito.

Answer (score -2):

You can **use** never and **verifyZeroInteractions**

```
//interaction with mockOne
    mockOne.add("one");
     
    //ordinary interaction 
    verify(mockOne).add("one");
     
    //we never interaction into the mock 
    verify(mockOne, never()).add("two");
     
    //verify we don't use in the mock 
    verifyZeroInteractions(mockTwo, mockThree);
```

*mark verifyZeroInteractions as deprecated in mockito-kotlin, too
introduce an alias for verifyNoInteractions

Comment: This is a lie. Are you sure this is dart code. When I add this code it throws exceptions saying The function 'never' isn't defined.